# NullPointerException at a .jsp when calling a method using a JPQL named query

Tags: java, spring, jsp, nullpointerexception

I am writing a `jsp` page that uses a `scriptlet` to call a method from a controller, which uses a method from a DAO, which performs a named query stored in a model corresponding to that DAO.  I want this controller method to return an `ArrayList` which I can iterate through to retrieve its values to display on the page.
When the `jsp` gets to the method call, it gives me an `NPE` at the controller method, specifically on the line which would call the query method.  What's more vexing is that I call a similar method earlier on the page and get no exceptions there.  My group has been using a Spring MVC framework with hibernate to handle our mapping.
I've tried to remove the non-essential parts of the code while leaving in things that might point to the solution.  Let me know if you need more information and I will update as soon as possible.
(I plan to learn to avoid scriptlets in the future, as all the questions I've read so far tell me to avoid them.) 
Here's the code:
ReportingController method:

```
public ArrayList<String> weekWorkPrints(User user, CurrentWeek week) {
    ArrayList<UserTime> timeList = userTimeDao
            .getPunchesForUserAscendingByTime(user);
    ArrayList<String> prints = new ArrayList<String>();
    prints.add(utc.convertPeriodToPrint(utc.timeWorkedForADay(
            week.getSunday(), timeList)));
    return prints;
}
```

UserTimeDao method calling a query:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional
public ArrayList<UserTime> getPunchesForUserAscendingByTime(User passedUser) {

    Query loginQuery = em
            .createNamedQuery("fetchAllUserTimesForUserAscend");
    loginQuery.setParameter("user", passedUser);

    return (ArrayList<UserTime>) loginQuery.getResultList();
}
```

Named Query within UserTime model:

```
    @NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "fetchAllUserTimes", query = "SELECT ut FROM UserTime ut"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "fetchAllUserTimesForUserDesc", query = "SELECT ut FROM UserTime ut WHERE ut.user = :user ORDER BY ut.userClockIn DESC"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "fetchAllUserTimesForUserAscend", query = "SELECT ut FROM UserTime ut WHERE ut.user = :user ORDER BY ut.userClockIn")})
```

JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@page import="models.*"%>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="models.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="controllers.ReportingController"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<jsp:useBean id="userDao" class="daos.UserDao" scope="request" />
<jsp:useBean id="reportControl" class="controllers.ReportingController"
scope="request" />
<jsp:useBean id="currentWeekControl"
class="controllers.CurrentWeekController" scope="session" />
<jsp:useBean id="userTimeDao" class="daos.UserTimeDao" scope="request" />
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/global.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reporting.css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Administrator - Reporting</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Administrator Home</h1>
        <%
            User loginUser = (User) session.getAttribute("loginUser");
        %>
        <p>
            Welcome,
            <%=loginUser.getUserName()%>!
        </p>
    </div>
<!-- ---- -->
                <table id="loggedTimeTable">
                    <%
                        CurrentWeek currentWeek = (CurrentWeek) session
                                .getAttribute("currentWeek");
                    %>
                    <!-- --- -->
                    <%
                        for (User iteratedUser : userDao.getAlphabeticalUsers()) {
                            ArrayList<String> weekPrintouts = reportControl.weekWorkPrints(
                                    iteratedUser, currentWeek);
                    %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%=iteratedUser.getLastName()%>, <%=iteratedUser.getFirstName()%>
                        </td>
                        <td><%=weekPrintouts.get(0)%></td>
                    </tr>
                    <%
                        }
                    %>
                </table>
```

The Null Pointer Exception:

```
2012-08-19 21:21:02.315::WARN:  Nested in org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controllers.ReportingController.weekWorkPrints(ReportingController.java:106)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp_002dpages.Reporting_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.jsp_002dpages.Reporting_jsp:196)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:93)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:373)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:470)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:726)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:285)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1093)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:322)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:184)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:155)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:726)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:206)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:829)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:514)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

Comment: can you please specify what is at line number `106` in `ReportingController.java`

Comment: line 106 is the bottom half of 

    ArrayList<UserTime> timeList = userTimeDao
   .getPunchesForUserAscendingByTime(user);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your useBean for reportControl is simply creating a brand new ReportingController, which does not have the UserDao injected.

What you are trying to do simply won't work in Spring MVC, and nor should it. The objective of MVC is to separate the Model, View and Controller, but you are trying to create an instance of a controller inside a view.

Instead, the controller method you have that returns the JSP name should first call your weekWorkPrints method and put the returned List in the Model so that the JSP can iterate through it.

Comment: Ah.  I guess my understanding of MVC is shakier than I thought.  Thanks for your answer.  Can you elaborate on what you mean by putting the list "in the Model" and how I can pass that list into something within the JSP?

Comment: Well, you must have a controller method mapped to the URL you use to view the JSP, right? The model is conceptually a set of all objects you want to expose to the view, but in more practical terms is represented by the org.springframework.ui.Model interface in Spring. There are a number of ways the controller can access the model, if you post the source of your controller method I could suggest one.